# How to dynamically set row height with autolayout and stack views inside

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Can't find working solution. A little bit lost in all this autolayout and constraints staff.
The task is trivial - need to optionally hide some info in table cell.

[image]

How to dynamically shrink row height when some stack view blocks are hidden?

I've already set:

```
TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 128;
```

and related constraints between last stack view bottom and superview (cell content view).But when this stack will be hidden then obviously there must be some other constraints.
I made other one to Main info block (visible always) and superview bottom with lower priority.
But that not working... can't figure out all that relation between constraints, priority and stack view layouts.

Want to mention that stack views have dynamic size too, due its internal context - basically multiline labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `hidden` property of your stack view, it is not longer visible, but is height is still not 0, and has influence on whole cell height. Better way to hide something and recalculate content view height - add height constraint to your stack view and set it to 0, when you hide it. But it is complicated, because height of your stack views depends on content. 
I suggest you to put your view into one big vertical stack view, then connect top and bottom constraints of this vertical stack view to content view. Stack view automatically adjusts height when it's child is hidden, so this may help you.

Comment: Ahh it's so simple! The here was: 'Stack view automatically adjusts height when it's child is hidden' tnx